# JavaScript - Display cost form dropdown list OnClick

Tags: javascript, php, html

Lets get this out of the way. "I know almost nothing about JavaScript"! Any of the JavaScript code I am using is taken form sites that show examples of JavaScript. As well, I have searched the Stackoverflow forum for people having similar issues. If I missed a topic that will fix my problem, please let me know.

I have a dropdown list that has a list of stock shares:

```
<select name="shares" id="shares">
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1500">1500</option>
</select>
```

I am currently using this JS code and it will displaying the cost to the screen for the only the first number in the dropdown list:

```
<script>
  var stock_position = <?php echo $stock_position; ?>;
  var shares = document.buy_shares.shares;
  var cost = stock_position * shares.value;
  document.write(cost);
</script>
```

However, I have no idea how to make the cost change when a new share amount is selected from the dropdown list. As well, I think I read somewhere that said "document.write()" might not be the best option to display the cost to the screen? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you have write a AJAX call to fetch the data from the Server and call it on change event of the select input

Answer (score 0):

I made this code for you. In this first I print your values in a `p` tag then when the user changes share it will again change the `p` tag html. Here is a fiddle link for a live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsh_kalsi01/00e770o6/)

```js
$("#demo").html($("#shares").val());

$("#shares").on('change',function(){
    var values = $(this).val();
     $("#demo").html(values);
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select name="shares" id="shares">
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1500">1500</option>
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: That works great at displaying the number from the dropdown list, however how do I edit your code to do the calculations for the price of the shares? thx!

Answer (score 0):

the variable I created name values you can use that variable for calculation like  values*stock_position  or any kind of calculation.

If you have stock position values from php then you have to use ajax for get that value in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vdbr24m7/

HTML:

```
<select name="shares" id="shares">
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
  <option value="1500">1500</option>
</select>

Cost : <span id="cost"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var stock_position = 10;// set by PHP

function showCost(shares){
    var cost = stock_position * shares;
    $("#cost").text(cost);
}
$(function() {
    var $list = $("#shares");
    $list.change(function(){
        showCost($(this).val());
    });
    showCost($list.val());
});
```

Hope this helps.